Inno Setup: How can I hide the wizards taskbar icon?
Introduction:
Inno Setup helps me in creating wizards and automated patches for several years now and I am really happy with that compiler. There is barely anything you cannot do with it and the code seems much easier to understand to me than from others (e.g. NSIS, Delphi, etc.).
Question:
What is the code for hiding the entire taskbar icon in Inno Setup 5.x (not just empty icon)?
Background info:
I am well aware that for standard installers this is not needed and would look suspicious. But I talk about those wizards who are part of a bigger installer (they need to have their own due to the way Windows handles environment variables and user group permissions) - imagine it like a container in a container. The outer one is displayed normally, but the inner one should be run "verysilent" even when the user uses it by double-clicking later (most of you already faced this by installing apps as it's not uncommon behaviour). I already managed to hide the setup window by using WizardForm.Hide - but that leaves me without window but still with taskbar icon (looks as unprofessional as a flashing console window on a client would).
What I tried already:

did online search in general
did thoroughly search Inno Setup's guide:  https://jrsoftware.org
searched explicit for relevant StackOverflow forum questions (the one targets Delphi does not work for IS)
searched explicit for relevent SuprerUser forum questions (https://superuser.com/questions/43206/how-can-i-hide-an-application-from-the-windows-taskbar: These tools are not silent and/or cannot implemented in Inno Setup before Form is created)
tried all Inno Setup parameters (silent, verysilent - it does not hide taskbar icon when executed by double-click)
tried with some code I found for Pascal/Lazarus online
simply guessed possible codes based on other commands
tried alternatives like NSIS, SFX archives (e.g. WinRAR) and VBScript - but all those lacks of the other urgently needed features Inno Setup have
searched Github repos for external tools that I could implement within Inno Setup
told IS to restart itself in verysilent mode automatically (don't affect the first double-click generates taskbar icon)
commands runhidden[Run] / SW_HIDE[Code] affect following instances only as they executed after IS was initialized
asked ChatGPT - she only tells me how to hide the window form or an icon from systray

What I know so far:


IS parameters or Inno Setups predefined own functions would not do the trick at all as they would not work on run by double-click
the taskbar icon is created very early at the beginning of InitializeSetup (even before InitializeWizard) so the user would notice a very quick flashing when insert target code here - the only chance to actually prevent any taskbar icon would be to do this via Preprocessor-Code (if possible).
I would avoid extern third party tools even there would exist a silent solution: 'Stealing' another programs taskbar icon is a type of code injection and could be easily mixed up with malware, that's not what I want.
theoretically wrapping is an option (put my installer into another SFX archive that extracts IS and call it with param /VERYSILENT), but that would increase the waiting time for several seconds and seems rather dirty solution to me.


Have you tried this? https://wixtoolset.org

Did you try using runhidden/SW_HIDE flag?

Nice ideas both, but that don't work for double-click the setup. I can tell IS to restart itself in verysilent mode or with runhidden [Run] / SW_HIDE [Code] or use external tools for any following instances but it does not change the way the first approach still shows flashing (empty) taskbar icon.
Do you know a way to suppress it within [Code] section, that would be the only real solution as far as I know.

Why fight it? Big corporate installers don't try and hide it. I prefer knowing that something is happening.

Your question is about hiding a button of inner/child installers. Now you object that with runhidden/SW_HIDE, you cannot hide the master installer button. That's a different problem.

Talking about inner/child was a comparison to better imagine the situation. If it was about the child only, of course your params were the ideal solution. What I try to achieve is a Inno Setup app thats looks as an invisible WinForm app, or in using other words as if IS already runs runhidden/SW_HIDE when starting it by double-click.

@Andrew Truckle: They do, show yourself. If you install a driver for example: In AMD/NVIDIA driver installation you only see the main installer with the ads in the GUI - the single components installers remain hidden. Firefox/Chrome run as user and watch you answering the UAC and display the non-admin installer if you deny the elevation. MSTeams hide the wizard (only show SplashScreen). Software that offer automated updates do so. Task scheduler entrys with system user run on entire other desktop.
I agree with you prefering a GUI, but for portable apps, updaters or sub-wizards I like it.

But in all these cases you somehow see that installation is going on. While you ask for completely hidden installer.

If you create a non-msi patch to distribute silent or a portable app, would you like to see a setup window. I think I explained it in my question.

I checked this code on Inno Setup Compiler 6.2.2. It hides the icon from the taskbar. The only note is that the icon appears along with the Message Box showing, for example, "Choosing the installation language".
    [Code]
    var
      function ShowWindow(hWnd: Integer; uType: Integer): Integer;
      external 'ShowWindow@user32.dll stdcall delayload';

      function GetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex: Integer): Longint;
      external 'GetWindowLongW@user32 stdcall delayload';
    
      function SetWindowLong(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; dwNewLong: Longint): Longint;
      external 'SetWindowLongW@user32.dll stdcall delayload';

    const
      GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8);
      GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);
      WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = $80;
        
    procedure InitializeWizard();
    var
      hWindow: HWND;

    begin
      hWindow := GetWindowLong(MainForm.Handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT);
      SetWindowLong(hWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
      ShowWindow(hWindow, SW_HIDE);
      //CreateCustomPages;
    end;


Excuse me, but I like to hide the taskbar icon, not the window. I already achieved hiding the window form. Though, I tested your code - icon still exists. Do you have another idea?

I checked it out. See all the details in my answer.

Please wait, I'll check it again.

Yes, it works - at least partly. The taskbar icon will be removed, but first if it had been shown. That means I can still see it flashing in the taskbar for 0,5 secconds. Is there a chance to get it removed even before it appears?

Unfortunately, I couldn't fix the flashing icon on the taskbar.
